# List Class in Python-Twitter

Tags: python-twitter

Despite a day's searching and trying I cannot get around the List Class of the python-twitter module.
The aim of the game is very simple, I want to retrieve all the followers (my students) I have previously grouped into a Twitter list called MyStudents.

I am stuck very early in the process as I am not even sure how to get an instance of the list class (I decalre an instance of the Api class without any problem):

The following

```
`list=twitter.List()`
```

seems to send back an empty set. And so do

```
`list=twitter.List(name='MyStudents')`
```

and the rather desperate

```
list=twitter.List('MyStudents')
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction ?

Thanks in advance